# Constants for using in SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"ru.pcask.clients",
                                            "ru.pcask.activities"
                                           })
@EntityScan(value={"ru.pcask.clients",
                   "ru.pcask.activities"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(value={"ru.pcask.clients",
                       "ru.pcask.activities"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

"ru.pcask.clients" seems to be a constant. But I don't know how to organize it?
I tried like this:

**Constants.java**

```
@Configuration
public class Constants {
    private static final String CLIENT = "ru.pcask.clients";

    @Bean
    public String getClientConst() {
        return this.CLIENT;
    }
}
```

But this seems to be a garbage. I don't even know how to use it in @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? do want the string `ru.pcask.clients` in another file? or do you simply want to import all the constants from a different file?

`@EntityScan` is used to search for components that are not in the base package as the main function only.

Comment: Even easier place your `Application` class in the `ru.pcask`, and only leave `@SpringBootApplication` and it will still work, without the additional annotations. And you won't need the constants that way.